# Are, or how are, polyuria and diuresis different?

Tags: terminology

http://wikidiff.com/diuresis/polyuria and http://neetprep.com/subject/U3ViamVjdDo1Ng==/topic/VG9waWM6NzEx/doubt/RG91YnQ6MTQ0MDc= appear to state that the terminology is identical, or provide unhelpfully similar and potentially automatically generated description of each:

http://wikidiff.com/diuresis/polyuria states that diureses is "excessive production of urine", and refers to polyuria as synonymous. It additionally states that polyuria is "production of an abnormally large amount of urine" and that diuresis is synonymous.

http://neetprep.com/subject/U3ViamVjdDo1Ng==/topic/VG9waWM6NzEx/doubt/RG91YnQ6MTQ0MDc= very directly states that their definitions appear to be identical, but anecdotally that they may be utilized during different conditions.

Comment: You state that "most websites appear..." so some websites don't provide identical definitions, have you considered those?

Comment: We expect questions to show some evidence of the effort you've taken to understand the problem. If you've found definitions of these terms that seem the same, could you cite those? Perhaps quote them briefly with a link, and point out why they seem the same, and why you think they should be different?

Comment: @BryanKrause, I believe that I have added what you request.

Comment: Probably better on SE Medical Sciences.

Comment: @David, are you able to transfer it? Nobody appears to be able to answer this.

Comment: No, only the mods like @BryanKrause (the diamond indicates he is a moderator). So what you can do is raise a flag and under "other" ask for the transfer. But it would be a good idea to first modify your question as he suggested. Alternatively, delete and post there.